# Viewing binary files in MSVS under Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, binary, file, windows-10

For ages I've been using MS visual studio 15 to view binary files, simply by doing file|open. My files have a custom extension, 'SQ3', but VS seemed to happily infer that they aren't text, and display them as binary. However, Win10 seems to have stopped that. Now if I do the same thing, a popup appears, asking me whether I want to find an application from the shop, or always use this application (presumably MSVS, the one I'm invoking from). There's a proceed button, but it doesn't respond. There seems to be no way that I can get VS to open and display the file.

Is there a way to stop the OS intervening so VS can do its thing?

Incidentally, having to rename files would be extremely inconvenient in this situation.  TIA

Thanks, that's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio go to *Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extensions*.
Add new entry to the list:

- Extension: *sq3*
- Editor: *Binary Editor*

Click *Add* and then *OK* to close the dialog. Files with .sq3 extension will now open with the hex editor when opening them or dragging them to Visual Studio.